# Blogger Soho theme header image does not cover full header width and height

Tags: html, css, blogger

I am using Blogger Soho theme and have problem placing a background image behind the header title + subscribe link. The image (named glitter1.jpg) will not cover the full width and height of the header band; it only wrap around the header title words.

I searched this forum but was not able to get a previous solution. Posts to Blogger product forum was ignored.

Blog url: https://retireby50sg.blogspot.com

Snippets of the codes around header image:

```
<div class='blog-name'>
                <b:section id='header' name='Header' showaddelement='false'>
                  <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='Retire by 50 in Singapore (Header)' type='Header' visible='true'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                      <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'>http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-S3EDENzAc5M/W081co1cPbI/AAAAAAAABjs/gDO0eWSzxmUM8oaKfcdmKanYu1iAB3pZACK4BGAYYCw/s1600/glitters1.jpg</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>300</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>705</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='useImage'>true</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='imagePlacement'>BEHIND</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>1140</b:widget-setting>
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
    <div class='header-widget'>
      <b:include cond='data:imagePlacement in {&quot;REPLACE&quot;, &quot;BEFORE_DESCRIPTION&quot;}' name='image'/>
      <b:include cond='data:imagePlacement not in {&quot;REPLACE&quot;, &quot;BEFORE_DESCRIPTION&quot;}' name='title'/>
```

Could you kindly help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.centered-top-container {
    background-image: url(\/\/4.bp.blogspot.com\/-S3EDENzAc5M\/W081co1cPbI\/AAAAAAAABjs\/gDO0eWSzxmUM8oaKfcdmKanYu1iAB3pZACK4BGAYYCw\/w1600\/glitters1.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your background image should be on the item with the class `centered-top-container`. Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.centered-top-container {
  background: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-S3EDENzAc5M/W081co1cPbI/AAAAAAAABjs/gDO0eWSzxmUM8oaKfcdmKanYu1iAB3pZACK4BGAYYCw/s1600/glitters1.jpg") center cover;
}
```

Comment: I've removed the center cover and appended background-image and it now works. Thank you for your earlier reply!